# Is there a product(s) to stream recorded videos, all at same given point in time

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming

I've been searching for a hardware or software product that can stream up at least 17 time stamped video recordings, all at the same point in time.  If I had 17 separate recordings of 17 different flight simulations for example, I would like the ability to fast forward/rewind to a given point in time and have these channels all stream the recordings from that point in time.  Any products I've come across so far can only work with a small number of channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a product called Calypso by Haivision

http://www.haivision.com/products/record-stream/calypso

I've spoken with their tech support and they claim it can do the time sync functionality I desire.

I recognize this product will be out of the price range for some looking for the same sort of thing.  The multiscreener app screaming drills mentions above looks promising, as does some other software products that website mentions.  I just do not have the time to check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Premiere and Final Cut Pro X can. Final Cut is particularly good at this. Look up multicam FCPX for some demos.

Comment: I see the multicam feature is able to sync multiple imported streams for editing in these products, but what about exporting?  I've started researching both Adobe Premiere and Final Cut Pro and haven't found anything yet that says either product will stream multiple sources to multiple destinations, all sources starting at a given point in time.

Comment: You're right about that, its great for syncing and viewing, but most editors assume you would want to watch one stream at a time. Can you tell me more what you're trying to achieve? How would you like to watch the video? What player would you use (QuickTime, VLC). What's the max resolution you'd want?

Comment: I would like to be able to play back training sessions that took place on multiple computers simultaneously.  I am flexible about what video format the recordings would be in.  The recordings would all be time synced.  The idea is that I could jump to x minutes after start and have each of these recordings streamed to a separate display for review at the same point in time.  I'd then proceed to fast forward/rewind, and have all the streams jump to that time.  I'd like to view each of the recordings on a separate display.  I am flexible about what player to use.  I'd prefer full HD res

Comment: Gotcha, this a really interesting problem. I'm sure there is a good very expensive broadcast solution but I'd like to research and see if I can figure this out. Now that you've got me thinking I can think of a dozen applications for this.

Comment: I found this multiscreener app: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/slade/know/3447. This looks promising. I would prep the videos by using the multicam FCPX function to synchronize and create several "tracks" with the exact same start and end time. It would be just as simple with Premiere. Ill have to test it out when I get home.